# Notebook display won't "work" since Nvidia driver installation

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

As title said, I have an issue with my built-in display of my Notebook. Since the day I installed the NVIDIA drivers I don't have output, *even unplugged from external Monitor*, on my built-in display.

**What I tried:**

- Unplug my external HDMI connected monitor.
- Set to "on-demand" in NVIDIA-SETTINGS
- Reboot & Reboot after unplugged external HDMI connected monitor.
- $ xrandr --auto
- Asked for help at [r/Ubuntu](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/) and got 0 responds so far.

[BTW: Installed all drivers for Nvidia and Intel from Lutris' documentation.](https://github.com/lutris/docs/blob/master/InstallingDrivers.md)

**xRandr:**

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767

DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 522mm x 294mm

1920x1080 60.00 + 144.00* 120.00 119.88 50.00 29.97 25.00 23.98

1680x1050 59.95

1600x1200 60.00

1440x900 59.89

1280x1024 75.02 60.02

1280x960 60.00

1280x720 60.00 59.94 50.00

1152x864 75.00

1024x768 75.03 70.07 60.00

960x1080 60.00

800x600 75.00 72.19 60.32 56.25

720x576 50.00

720x480 59.94

640x480 75.00 72.81 59.94 59.93
```

**My Notebook:**

- OS: Ubuntu 21.10 x86_64
- Host: HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop 16-a
- Kernel: 5.13.0-28-generic
- DE: GNOME 40.5
- CPU: Intel i5-10300H (8) @ 4.500GHz
- dGPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobi
- iGPU: Intel CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Grap
- Memory: 16GB

Comment: Avoid "on-demand" and see how it goes.

Comment: I already tried that and it didn't do any affect.

Comment: Tried what exactly? If not "on-demand" then you have to select iGPU or dGPU (by selecting the respective profiles in the Nvidia X Server Settings) and reboot. What happens in one case and the other? Have you checked the screens settings?

Comment: I've selected the dGPU, no change. And  as far as i know, when selecting iGPU, i don't have the gaming power of my dGPU.

Comment: Or is this totally wrong with gaming ?

Comment: @ChanganAuto screen setting u refer to display settings in the system settings section? If yes, only the external monitor is listed there